# What is the meaning of these red bars in git file difference

Tags: git, git-diff

[image]

There is a red bar after + sign. What is this ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Potentially bad indentation. You may have used tabs when you configured Git to prefer spaces, or vice-versa.

Check `git config core.whitespace`; it might contain `tab-in-indent`, `space-before-tab`, or `indent-with-non-tab`. You should change it to suit your preferences if this isn’t really a mistake.

Answer (score 11):

Here are the possible values for the `core.whitespace`.
Your configuration value will be one of the tabs value below

#### core.whitespace

> A comma separated list of common whitespace problems to notice.
>   git diff will use `color.diff.whitespace` to highlight them, and git apply
>   `--whitespace=error` will consider them as errors.
>   You can prefix - to disable any of them (e.g. -trailing-space):

- #### blank-at-eol

  treats trailing whitespaces at the end of the line as an error (enabled by default).
- #### space-before-tab###

  treats a space character that appears immediately before a tab character in the initial indent part of the line as an error (enabled by default).
- #### indent-with-non-tab

  treats a line that is indented with space characters instead of the equivalent tabs as an error (not enabled by default).
- #### tab-in-indent

  treats a tab character in the initial indent part of the line as an error (not enabled by default).
- #### blank-at-eof

  treats blank lines added at the end of file as an error (enabled by default).
- #### trailing-space

  a short-hand to cover both `blank-at-eol` and `blank-at-eof`.
- #### cr-at-eol

  treats a carriage-return at the end of line as part of the line terminator, i.e. with it, trailing-space does not trigger if the character before such a carriage-return is not a whitespace (not enabled by default).
- #### tabwidth=n

  tells how many character positions a tab occupies; this is relevant for indent-with-non-tab and when Git fixes tab-in-indent errors. The default tab width is 8. Allowed values are 1 to 63.

---

Sample for output when tabs are uses as the configuration value:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

This means you have unwanted extra spaces in your source. You should delete those unwanted spaces to keep clean.

Comment: Yes! The red block is extra space in my case.